# How to take a scalar of a certain value in another column based on the value of a certain column in a Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns `A` and `B`. I want to take the scalar of column `B` based on the value of column `A`. I used `loc` and `.value` `[0]`

My data volume is relatively small, the main problem is to see whether the syntax of the code is correct. `.value` seems to be deprecated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df[['A', 'B']] = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)))
df1 = df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].values[0]
print(df1)
```

The result is

```
5
```

Can this code be optimized?

```
df1 = df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].values[0]
```

`numpy` is faster:

```
%timeit df1 = df[df['A'] == 4].B.iloc[0]
723 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df1=df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].to_numpy()[0]
513 µs ± 4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df1 = df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].iloc[0]
521 µs ± 20.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Instead of `values[0]` you can use `to_numpy()[0]`. That might run a bit faster.

Comment: not sure if this is faster ``df.set_index('A').at[4,'B']``. Also, your current code can be written as ``df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].item()``. Again, you may have to test

Comment: My data volume is relatively small, the main problem is to see whether the syntax of the code is correct. `.value` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: @jaried Based on your last comment, closing this as a duplicate. Since `to_numpy` vs `values` has already been discussed.

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Ya, then I reopen. Because I think `.to_numpy()` here is used not good idea (added to answer why)

Comment: @jezrael I think OP just needed to validate his syntax. So `to_numpy` is a perfectly good answer. But again, no point discussing this with you. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need optimalized with return some value if condition failed use `next` with `iter`:

```
a = next(iter(df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B']), 'no match')
print (a)
5

a = next(iter(df.loc[df['A'] == 1000, 'B']), 'no match')
print (a)
no match
```

If values always matching is possible use [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html), but this failed if no match, so better not use:

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 4, 'B'].to_numpy()[0]
#but this failed
#df.loc[df['A'] == 1000, 'B'].to_numpy()[0]
```